# ReactJS setState not updating when making jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have this code in JSX:

```html
<script type="text/babel">
  function Rows(){
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(()=>{

      $.ajax(
      {
        url:"http://localhost:8080/api/manage/products/all",
        success:function(data){
          setItems(data);
          console.log(data);
          console.log(items);
          setIsLoaded(true);
        }
      });

    },[]);

      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          {items.map((o)=>{
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{o.id}</th>
                <td>{o.prdname}</td>
              </tr>
          })}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Rows />,document.getElementById("clientBody"));

</script>
```

I get the `data` array output in the console as expected but for the `items` I get an empty array. What is the problem and how do I solve it? I want to use hooks and jQuery for that.

Comment: sorry it does not. i took a look at it before i asked

Comment: Are you certain the proposed duplicate does not answer your question?  It appears to be the same issue, with the same underlying cause (from what I see), with a proper answer.  If the proposed duplicate truly does not answer your question, can you specify in what way you believe your situation differs, to better enable the community to provide you with help?  Thanks, and happy coding!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console as well?

Comment: The linked answer should explain that `setItems(data)` does not update `items` in the current context. `items` is updated on the next render, therefore `console.log(items)` directly after `setItems(data)` displays the old `items`. If you want to use the new value you could just reference `data` instead of `items`. If you rather have an updated label you could introduce a new local variable `const items = data`, then `setItems(items)` to update the state on the next render. You can then freely use `items` (within the callback).

Comment: no error exept a warning indicating that i am using the in-browser babel

Comment: please use axios calls or fetch .. i never understood jquery in react .. it defeats its purpose